# Can not open/edit events in Kendo Scheduler on a mobile device

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

For example in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index

On a desktop browser, clicking on the event opens an editor. On a mobile touch device, tapping on the event does nothing. This repros also when running Chrome device emulation as iPhone.

Telerik claims that this works here:
   http://www.telerik.com/forums/creating-or-editing-event-in-mobile-browser
so I don't understand how they can make that claim.

Can someone please confirm that this does not work, or if I'm doing something wrong? I am just evaluating their product at this stage, so I do not have paid support subscription required to reply on that forum thread.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my question. On mobile devices, the scheduler needs to be configured for mobile using mobile:"phone" or mobile:"tablet", as well as instantiate a kendo.mobile.Application.

Here's an example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/uCiNU

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post you code, this helped me